# Dart Truncates HttpClientResponse

Tags: json, dart, flutter, httpresponse

Have been trying to solve this issue for several days now. The code successfully gives me the JSON data, but is missing many chunks, leaving me unable to parse it into objects. The code and output is below. Have researched a lot and any suggestions are welcome.

```
  class TBAState extends State<TBAData>{
  String url = "http://www.thebluealliance.com/api/v3/status";
  HttpClient myhttp = new HttpClient();
  List data;
  List cellTitle;

  Future getSWData() async {

    myhttp.getUrl(Uri.parse(url)).then((HttpClientRequest request) {
      request.headers.set("accept", "application/json");
      request.headers.set("X-TBA-Auth-Key", "XXXXX");
      return request.close();
    }).then((HttpClientResponse response) {
      response.transform(utf8.decoder).listen((contents) {
       // print(contents);
      });
    });
    myhttp.get('www.thebluealliance.com', 80, '/api/v3/teams/0/simple') 
    .then((HttpClientRequest request){
      request.headers.set("accept", "application/json");
      request.headers.set("X-TBA-Auth-Key", "XXXX");
    return request.close();
    })
      .then((HttpClientResponse response) {

      response.transform(utf8.decoder).listen((content) {
        //buffer.writeAll(content.toString());
        print(content);

        });

    });
  }
}
```

Some OUTPUT:

"team_number": 6
},

{<…> <- TRUNCATES

flutter: Brookman & Parkville High School and Center for Mathematics,

Science, and Computer Science",

"nickname": "Team007",

"state_prov": "MD",

"team_number": 7

},

{

---

```
 Error: 
Dart Error: Unhandled exception:
FormatException: Unterminated string (at line 42, character 155)
...y/US Army Aberdeen Test Center/Moffatt & Nichol/Baltimore Area Alliance/Mr.
^
#0      _ChunkedJsonParser.fail (dart:convert/runtime/libconvert_patch.dart:1358:5)
#1      _ChunkedJsonParser.close (dart:convert/runtime/libconvert_patch.dart:504:9)
#2      _parseJson (dart:convert/runtime/libconvert_patch.dart:30:10)
#3      JsonDecoder.convert (dart:convert/json.dart:540:36)
#4      JsonCodec.decode (dart:convert/json.dart:167:41)
#5      TBAState.getSWData
```

Comment: Do you get the same result if you check it with an HTTP tool like postman?

Comment: @JacobPhillips I've never used Postman before but I'm not the owner of the API, not sure if that makes a difference. Frustrating problem because it truncates a section in random places.

Comment: @JacobPhillips Update, tested with Postman and returns the correct JSON, so something going on with Dart instead an API is working fine. Still stuck.

Comment: Log output is often truncated. Rather investigate the response in the debugger.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Sorry, I dont understand. Can you be more specific?

Comment: If you print in Flutter, the output might get truncated if too long.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer That could be part of it but when I try to assign objects to the JSON, I get errors that the string does not terminate, probably due to the truncation. So that leads me to think that its truncating the actually JSON not the output.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer And I get the error right at the spot of truncation.

Comment: If you get an error, pleas add the exact and full error message to the questiin.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182061/discussion-between-yzet00-and-gunter-zochbauer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed: the issue was in the transformation of the HttpClientResonse. Correct code:

```
class TBAState extends State<TBAData>{

  HttpClient myhttp = new HttpClient();
  List<dynamic> data;
  List cellTitle;
  List<Team> teamData;

  Future getSWData() async {


    myhttp.get('www.thebluealliance.com', 80, '/api/v3/status').then((HttpClientRequest request) {
      request.headers.set("accept", "application/json");
      request.headers.set("X-TBA-Auth-Key", "XXXX");
      return request.close();
    }).then((HttpClientResponse response) {
      response.transform(utf8.decoder).listen((contents) {
       //print(contents);
      });
    });
    myhttp.get('www.thebluealliance.com', 80, '/api/v3/teams/0/simple') 
    .then((HttpClientRequest request) {
      request.headers.set("accept", "application/json");
      request.headers.set("X-TBA-Auth-Key", "XXXX");
    return request.close();
    })
      .then((HttpClientResponse response) {
       response.transform(utf8.decoder).transform(json.decoder).listen((data) {
        print(data.toString());
        setState(() {
        TeamList myTeamsL = new TeamList.fromJson(data);
        teamData = myTeamsL.teams;
                });

      });

    });
  }
}
```